# Yo command not found

Tags: npm, yeoman, yarnpkg, linux-mint

I downloaded the latest Node/Npm version from npmjs.com, extracted it and added the bin directory to my $PATH.

I installed yarn. Used yarn to install a few packages - everything worked fine.

I then tried to install Yeoman (yo) package. Tried both

```
yarn add global yo
npm install -g yo
```

Both seem to work, but I can't find the yo executable. I looked in the node_modules, npm bin directory, searched the file system all to no avail.

I added a Npm global module directory to ~/.npmrs but that remains empty.

What am I missing?